# How can I name and call a jQuery function?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
 $('#EID').change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Administration/stats",
                    data: { DataSource: $('#DataSource').val(),
                            EID: $('#EID').val()
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#TID').html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
```

This works good but I want to be able to call the function () at other times and not just when EID changes. Can someone show me how I can pull out the function code into a separate block with a name and then call that function name.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
function doSomething() {
    $.ajax(...);
}

$('#EID').change(doSomething);
```

Note that you must **not** add `()` after the function name since you want to pass the function, not its return value.

In case you wanted to pass some parameter to the function, you'd do it like this:

```
function doSomething(someParam) {
    $.ajax(...);
}

$('#EID').change(function() {
    doSomething(whateverSomeParamShouldBe);
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This is exactly what I need. If I wanted to pass the parameter $('#EID').val() then how would I declare the parameter and then use it inside of the function?

Comment: @Samantha: It's usually best to do this wrapped in a function containing all of your stuff (called a "scoping function") because otherwise you create global symbols, and the global space in web browsers is crowded enough already. Two examples: http://pastie.org/2792207

Comment: @Samantha: *" If I wanted to pass the parameter $('#EID').val() then how would I declare the parameter and then use it inside of the function?"* Exactly the way ThiefMaster demonstrated in the second half of his answer, example: http://pastie.org/2792210

Comment: Is a semi-colon needed after the function definition? I can't seem to get the code to work.

Comment: Then show the code... a semicolon is almost never required in JS.

Comment: @Samantha: *"Is a semi-colon needed after the function definition?"* Not if it's a function *declaration* as shown in ThiefMaster's answer. If it's a function *expression* that's part of an assignment statement (`var x = function() { ... };`), then yes, a semicolon is required (semicolons are required at the ends of statements). However, thanks to the [Horror that is Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9), you frequently get away without actually typing it. Never intentionally rely on that.

Comment: JavaScript does not require semicolons. ASI is a horrible thing though so simply write your code as if they were required.

Answer (score 0):

Well , the other thing you can do for someone looking for answer now  is  to trigger the function

```
$('#EID').change (function (){
    //your code here;
});
```

Some other function or code you want to call the previous unnamed function , you can simply do;

```
$('#classOrId).eventYouwannaUse (function (){
$('#EID').change ();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use on(); function and then define the function name

```
$('#EID').on('change' , ChangeEventfuncCode);
function ChangeEventfuncCode(){
 //your code ......
}
```

And then call the function anywhere you want..;

```
$('.classOrId').whateverEvent(function (){


//your code......
ChangeEventfuncCode();
});
```

Comment: duplicate answer, remove one.